# Can Windows Service work on shared hosting?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

Can Windows Service work on shared hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the hosting and the windows service.

If your service can work in medium trust environments, then there should be no problem (apart from convincing the hosting company to install it).

Comment: What is medium trust environment?

Comment: @PARTH - http://help.godaddy.com/article/1039 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx